# Apply jqueryUI interaction attributes to newly added DOM elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

So I start off with an element of class="list" that are defined as .sortable.  Now if I create another element of class="list" via jquery, it does not inherit the same definition that I had already defined.

Now, I got around that by throwing the definition into a function and then call the function upon initial load and as well as every time I add a new element.  Is this the best method? Or is there a more appropriate method of doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/S24d4/11/

Comment: if you change the DOM structure, you need to call the functions again to apply to the new elements. I'm not sure if it's the best method but you need to call them -some how- again

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [jQuery's .live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/). This will bind things to DOM elements added later.

Comment: Thing about live() is that it essentially does the same thing that I did.   It seems I can only tie it to the click event for my button... at least, that's the best I can think of.  Ideally, if the live() functionality could be used on a 'create' event, it would seem to fit the bill.  Closest thing I've found so far is the http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery plugin .

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood--I was thinking you were binding a handler, not calling a method on it. Although seems like it'd be easy enough to create a custom event to what you wanted. Never tried it, though.